# Are there any copyright or license issues associated with modifying inbuilt Flutter widgets and using it in my project?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I wanted to modify a part of the widget ReorderableListView which is provided in Material.dart. I was thinking of copying the source code for it and creating a new file called CustomReorderableListView and using it in the project. Are there any consequences related to copyright or license if I do such a thing?
Below is what is mentioned at the start of the code for the widget -

```
//Copyright 2014 The Flutter Authors. All rights reserved.
//Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
//found in the LICENSE file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter is an open-source project. If anything programmers are encouraged to modify existing widgets to fit their own ideas or project in any way they want.

You can read more about it at: https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq